# How to fix Python Pygame image error in window

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to load a png file to python by pygame and it doesn't work
this is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
carImage = pygame.image.load('you.png')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImage,(x,y))
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)
    crashed = False
    while not crashed:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               crashed = True
       gameDisplay.fill(white)
       car(x,y)
       pygame.display.update()
       clock.tick(24)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

and it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Dawn/PycharmProjects/snakegame/snake.py", line 13, in 
>   carImage = pygame.image.load('you.png')
>
> pygame.error: Couldn't open you.png

Please help me I don't know why this keep showing.

I'm using window 10 now and I did the `C: \.\...\you.png` method
but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42344060/8183470), it's recommended to use relative paths instead. It's always better to do so, since you don't have to care about '\', '/' or OS (someone already did it for us :v).

The problem seems to be it, because the code below works well for me. It's been considered you have an **images_store** folder to store your images at same father directory as your .py file (of course, you can change it any way you want).

```
import pygame
import os.path as osp
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

display_width, display_height = 800, 600
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

current_path = osp.dirname(__file__)                          # Where your .py file is located
image_path = osp.join(current_path, 'images_store')           # The image folder path
carImage = pygame.image.load(osp.join(image_path, 'you.png'))


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def car(x,y):
   gameDisplay.blit(carImage, (x, y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
crashed = False
while not crashed:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           crashed = True
   gameDisplay.fill(white)
   car(x,y)
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(24)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

p.s.1 - See more information about *os.path* [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

p.s.2 - I'm using MacOS.