# Why am I unable to load an image using pygame module?

Tags: python, pygame

Following an online game building tutorial on Youtube, I am trying to build a game but whenever i enter this code it always comes out with this syntax error:

```
line 11, in <module>
    icon = pygame.image.load('burger.png')
pygame.error: Couldn't open burger.png
```

what should I do?

Comment: where is situated the image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - error: couldn't open .png file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335678/python-error-couldnt-open-png-file)

Comment: On hard drive, in same folder as the code itself but with all other games i had built and put there

Comment: @maroofhamid if the code is in the projects root folder, see my answer below for ensuring you provide the correct relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing to do with Pygame itself. But your file location. Do you have it in the same folder as your .py script (aka your *root* folder)? If yes, check this thread out: [Opening images with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387069/open-images-python)